# Why does non-working "del" in a function affect my imports?

Tags: python

The code is like this:

```
import numpy as np

def f1():
    if False:
        del np
        import numpy as np
    return np.zeros(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    a = f1()
```

When I run this code, I get the error message:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'np' referenced before assignment`

Why does 'np' become local?

The "if False" block should not affect my program at all, since it cannot be executed.

But when I delete the "if" block, the code works.

Comment: Because `import numpy as no` is an implicit assignment to the variable `np`, and any assignments inside a function make the variable local **at compile time**

Comment: In your case, the assignment happens because inside the `if` block, `np` was imported, thus `np` becomes a declared local assignment inside `f1`. As the assignment never happens, it will then trigger the exception as shown.

Comment: `import numpy as np` inside the function is an assignment to a local name `np` that hides the global `np`. The statement.on the prior line, `del np`, is treated by the Python compiler as referencing the local name which you can't do before it's created.  It doesn't matter that it's surrounded by `if False:`—the Python compiler does not treat that as dead code.